# Meaning of function applied to differential

Tags: measure-theory, notation

In exercise 2.1.5 of http://cims.nyu.edu/~zeitouni/cupbook.pdf, it asks us to prove that for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, the Stieltjes transform $S(z)$ of the semicircle law equals
$$S(z) = \int \frac{1}{\lambda-z}\sigma(d\lambda) =
\frac{-z + \sqrt{z^2-4}}{2z} $$
where $\sigma(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{4-x^2}\mathbb{1}_{|x|\leq 2}.$

What is the meaning of $\sigma(d\lambda)$ in the integral?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of considering $\sigma$ as a function, you should consider it as a measure with density $\sigma(x)$. Then the notation $\sigma(d\lambda)$ simply means that the integration is done with respect to the measure $\sigma$ in the variable $\lambda$.

I've usually seen the notation $d\sigma(\lambda)$ used instead to indicate the same thing.

I'm basing this on the notation used in the definition of the Stieltjes transform (Definition 2.4.1) in the text, and comparing it to how I've seen the Stieltjes transform defined elsewhere. Furthermore, a straightforward computation shows that this interpretation of $\sigma(d\lambda)$ gives you the correct result.

Comment: I don't know much about densities of measures but basically $\sigma(d\lambda) = \sigma(\lambda) d\lambda$?

Comment: Yup. That's the correct interpretation.